# Having trouble with limit

Tags: limits

$$\lim \nolimits_{a\to b}\frac{a^{2}-(b+1)a+b}{a^{3}-b^{3}} $$
Need some help to solve it.
I tried hopitals but cant get the answer.

Comment: What went wrong with what you tried?

Comment: **HINT**: Try factorizing the numerator and denominator first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have the following equivalences for $a\neq b$
\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2-(b+1)a+b}{a^3-b^3}&=\frac{a^2-ab-a+b}{(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)},\qquad a\neq b\\
&=\frac{(a-b)(a-1)}{(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)},\qquad a\neq b\\
&=\frac{a-1}{a^2+ab+b^2}
\end{align*}
It follows $$\lim_{a\to b}\frac{a^2-(b+1)a+b}{a^3-b^3}=\frac{b-1}{3b^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Factor $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and rearrange the numerator as well $a^2-(b+1)a+b=(a-1)(a-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that $\frac{(a^2-(b+1)a+b}{a^3-b^3}=\frac{a-1}{a^2+ab+b^2}$

Answer (score 0):

In the numinator we have $a^2  -(b+1)a + b$ =$(a-b)(a-1)$. Moreover the denominator $a^3 - b^3$ can be written as $(a-b)(a^2  + ab + b^2)$. Evaluating the fraction gives $\frac{a-1}{a^2+ab+b^2}$ and so the limit is $\frac{b-1}{3b^2}$ as $a$$\rightarrow$$b$.